# Unable to select bokeh tools

Tags: google-chrome, python-3.x, bokeh

I have been happily using bokeh to create plots.

However, now when I create a new chart or load a previous chart, I am unable to change the selection of tools. **Selecting tools does not function**

- In Chrome settings, i have turned javaScript off and on again
- In Chrome I have also reset settings per here
  https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/3296214?hl=en
- I have restarted the machine several times.
- Using a different computer, the tools in the same chart can be selected just fine, so its not the chart itself and I presumed the browser

**My question is, how else can I "reset" Chrome? Or, if its not the browser, what else does Bokeh depend on to allow tool selection?**

(using Anaconda 3.4, Bokeh 0.9.1, Windows 7, Chrome 44.0.2403.107 m)

Comment: Potentially a browser specific problem. Has it previously worked with this particular configuration? Does it work on other browsers or versions of Chrome?

Comment: Yes, it was previously working well in this configuration of Chrome. Unfortunately, IE blocks bokeh completely and displays a blank screen (and being behind a corporate firewall without admin rights prevents installation of other browsers). Any advice gratefully received, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else stumped by this, here's the resolution:

Its related to Chrome expecting a touchscreen on my (non-touchscreen) laptop.
Following the instructions below fixed it.

http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.10.0/docs/faq.html#are-the-tools-not-working-in-chrome-cromium

> If you have a device with touchscreen capabilities, is possible that Chrome/Chromium is “flagged” to capture touch events which makes not possible to interact with the Bokeh tools with you mouse.
>
> To solve this issue you need to configure Chrome/Cromium going to the url bar and pasting the following:
>
> chrome://flags/#touch-events
>
> then you will see something like:
>
> Enable touch events Mac, Windows, Linux, Chrome OS Force touchscreen support to always be enabled or disabled, or to be enabled when a touchscreen is detected on startup (Automatic, the default). #touch-events
>
> and a drop-down button that you have to set to Disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately time marches on, and four years later this answer no longer works for Chrome 74.0.3729.169.

There is a plethora of flags related to "touch":

#touch-events   (which is disabled by default now)

and

#top-chrome-touch-ui
  #disable-touch-adjustment
  #enable-touch-drag-drop
  #document-passive-event-listeners
  #passive-event-listeners-due-to-fling
  #enable-resampling-input-events

I have disabled the others in various combinations, and the behavior of Bokeh tools doesn't change.  It will take a random number of mouse clicks to get the reset tool to work, or to turn on/off the pan and zoom tools.

The tools work perfectly in both Firefox and Edge, so it's definitely a Chrome problem, still unsolved.